# How to write the result (from python) to mongodb (in json)?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, import

I am now writing a Job-to-Job List. For a JobID, I would like to ouptput its similar jobs (by self-defined score in descending order). For example, the structure should be:

```
"_id":"abcd","job":1234,"jobList":[{"job":1,"score":0.9},{"job":2,"score":0.8},{"job":3,"score":0.7}]}
```

Here JobID is 1234 and job 1,2,3 are its similar jobs listed by name-score pairs. 
And my python codes are:

```
def sortSparseMatrix(m, rev=True, only_indices=True):
    f=open("/root/workspace/PythonOutPut/test.json",'wb')
    w=csv.writer(f,dialect='excel')
    col_list = [None] * (m.shape[0])
    j=0
    for i in xrange(m.shape[0]):

        d=m.getrow(i)

        if len(d.indices) != 0:
            s=zip(d.indices, d.data)
            s.sort(key=lambda v:v[1], reverse=True)
            if only_indices:
                col_list[j] =[[element[0],element[1]] for element in s]
                col_list[j]=col_list[j][0:4]

                h1 = u'Job'+":" +str(col_list[j][0][0])+","
                json.dump(h1,f)



                h2=[]
                h3=u'JobList'+":"
                json.dump(h3,f)
                for subrow in col_list[j][1:]:
                   h2.append(u'{Job'+":"+str(subrow[0])+","u'score'+":"+str(subrow[1])+"}")
                json.dump(h2,f)
                del col_list[j][:]
                j=j+1
```

where d contains unsorted name-score pairs with respect to JobID: `col_list[j][0][0]` (After sorting, the most similar job (highest score) with `JobID(col_list[j][0][0])` is itself).d.data is the score and `[element[0],element[1]]` is the name-score pair. I would like to keep the most similar three jobs w.r.t. JobID. I would like to dump h1 (to show JobID) first, and output the list of similar jobs in h2.

I typed 'mongodbimport --db test_database -- collection TestOfJSON --type csv --file /as above/ --fields JobList'. It can import the result to mongodb. However, it is only one JobID with many fields. But what I want is JobID associated with its similar Job's name-score pairs only. How should I do? thanks

Comment: You shall simplify your question, there is a lot of unnecessary stuff. If your question is how to write some data structure into MOngoDB, you shall assign the value to some variable and then show us, how you attempted to put it into MongoDB. Remove remaining code, which is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: hi, I typed 'mongodbimport --db test_database -- collection TestOfJSON --type csv --file /as above/ --fields JobList'. It can import the result to mongodb. However, it is a JobID with many fields. But what I want is JobID associated with its similar Job's name-score pairs only.

Comment: Your additional information belongs to your question. It is hard to read it from comments (many people will not read all the comments, everyone reads most of your question, if it is not too long)